# Strange behavior of .loadby sos clr

Tags: .net, windbg

I am analyzing a 64 bits managed dump using 64 bits version of WinDbg and observe a strange thing - `.loadby sos clr` works if I run it before `.imgscan /l` and does not work if I run it after.

I also noted that if I ran `.imgscan /l` first, there is still a way to load sos, but it is very crooked:

1. `.loadby sos clr` (fails)
2. `.load sosex.dll`
3. `.loadby sos clr` (does not fail, but `.chain` shows nothing)
4. `!bhi` or `!lhi` (depends on whether the heap index already exists)
5. `.chain` - Hooray, there is something there, but not exactly sos.dll!

Please, observe:

**Attempt 1 - loading sos before running imgscan**

[image]

```
0:000> .chain
Extension DLL search Path:
    E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\WINXP;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext\arcade;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\pri;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64;C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Dbg\EngineExtensions;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools\;%BPADir%;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;D:\Anaconda;D:\Anaconda\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;E:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\pg95\bin;E:\Program Files\Git\cmd;E:\Program Files\nodejs\;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;E:\Utils;c:\dayforce\DayforceDEV\Utils;C:\Program Files\nodejs;c:\Program Files\WinRAR;c:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonEE9.6N\bin;C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Roaming\npm
Extension DLL chain:
    dbghelp: image 10.0.15063.468, API 10.0.6, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\dbghelp.dll]
    ext: image 10.0.15063.468, API 1.0.0, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext\ext.dll]
    exts: image 10.0.15063.468, API 1.0.0, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\WINXP\exts.dll]
    uext: image 10.0.15063.468, API 1.0.0, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext\uext.dll]
    ntsdexts: image 10.0.15063.468, API 1.0.0, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\WINXP\ntsdexts.dll]
0:000> .loadby sos clr
0:000> .chain
Extension DLL search Path:
    E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\WINXP;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext\arcade;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\pri;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64;C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Dbg\EngineExtensions;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools\;%BPADir%;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;D:\Anaconda;D:\Anaconda\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;E:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\pg95\bin;E:\Program Files\Git\cmd;E:\Program Files\nodejs\;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;E:\Utils;c:\dayforce\DayforceDEV\Utils;C:\Program Files\nodejs;c:\Program Files\WinRAR;c:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonEE9.6N\bin;C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Roaming\npm
Extension DLL chain:
    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\sos: image 4.6.1590.0, API 1.0.0, built Thu Jul 14 15:52:38 2016
        [path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\sos.dll]
    dbghelp: image 10.0.15063.468, API 10.0.6, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\dbghelp.dll]
    ext: image 10.0.15063.468, API 1.0.0, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext\ext.dll]
    exts: image 10.0.15063.468, API 1.0.0, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\WINXP\exts.dll]
    uext: image 10.0.15063.468, API 1.0.0, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext\uext.dll]
    ntsdexts: image 10.0.15063.468, API 1.0.0, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\WINXP\ntsdexts.dll]
```

**Attempt 2 - loading sos after running imgscan**

[image]

...

[image]

```
0:000> .chain
Extension DLL search Path:
    E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\WINXP;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext\arcade;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\pri;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64;C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Dbg\EngineExtensions;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools\;%BPADir%;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;D:\Anaconda;D:\Anaconda\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;E:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\pg95\bin;E:\Program Files\Git\cmd;E:\Program Files\nodejs\;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;E:\Utils;c:\dayforce\DayforceDEV\Utils;C:\Program Files\nodejs;c:\Program Files\WinRAR;c:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonEE9.6N\bin;C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Roaming\npm
Extension DLL chain:
    dbghelp: image 10.0.15063.468, API 10.0.6, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\dbghelp.dll]
    ext: image 10.0.15063.468, API 1.0.0, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext\ext.dll]
    exts: image 10.0.15063.468, API 1.0.0, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\WINXP\exts.dll]
    uext: image 10.0.15063.468, API 1.0.0, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext\uext.dll]
    ntsdexts: image 10.0.15063.468, API 1.0.0, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\WINXP\ntsdexts.dll]
0:000> .imgscan /l
MZ at 00000000`00460000, prot 00000002, type 01000000 - size 4e000
  Name: msvcm90.dll
  Loaded msvcm90.dll module
MZ at 00000000`5c900000, prot 00000002, type 01000000 - size 4e000
  Name: msvcm90.dll
  Loaded msvcm90.dll module
MZ at 00000000`5d3c0000, prot 00000002, type 01000000 - size a3000
  Name: MSVCR90.dll
  Loaded MSVCR90.dll module

...

MZ at 00007fff`76720000, prot 00000002, type 01000000 - size 212000
  Name: combase.dll
  Loaded combase.dll module
MZ at 00007fff`76940000, prot 00000002, type 01000000 - size c6000
  Name: OLEAUT32.dll
  Loaded OLEAUT32.dll module
MZ at 00007fff`76a50000, prot 00000002, type 01000000 - size 1ad000
  Name: ntdll.dll
  Loaded ntdll.dll module
0:000> .loadby sos clr
The call to LoadLibrary(sos) failed, Win32 error 0n2
    "The system cannot find the file specified."
Please check your debugger configuration and/or network access.
```

**Attempt 3 - loading sos after imgscan and sosex.lhi**

[image]

```
0:000> .loadby sos clr
The call to LoadLibrary(sos) failed, Win32 error 0n2
    "The system cannot find the file specified."
Please check your debugger configuration and/or network access.
0:000> .load e:\utils\sosex\64\sosex.dll
0:000> .chain
Extension DLL search Path:
    E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\WINXP;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext\arcade;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\pri;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64;C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Dbg\EngineExtensions;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools\;%BPADir%;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;D:\Anaconda;D:\Anaconda\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;E:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\pg95\bin;E:\Program Files\Git\cmd;E:\Program Files\nodejs\;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;E:\Utils;c:\dayforce\DayforceDEV\Utils;C:\Program Files\nodejs;c:\Program Files\WinRAR;c:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonEE9.6N\bin;C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Roaming\npm
Extension DLL chain:
    e:\utils\sosex\64\sosex.dll: image 4.6.0.0, API 1.0.0, built Mon Mar 14 10:11:26 2016
        [path: e:\utils\sosex\64\sosex.dll]
    dbghelp: image 10.0.15063.468, API 10.0.6, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\dbghelp.dll]
    ext: image 10.0.15063.468, API 1.0.0, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext\ext.dll]
    exts: image 10.0.15063.468, API 1.0.0, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\WINXP\exts.dll]
    uext: image 10.0.15063.468, API 1.0.0, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext\uext.dll]
    ntsdexts: image 10.0.15063.468, API 1.0.0, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\WINXP\ntsdexts.dll]
0:000> .loadby sos clr
0:000> .chain
Extension DLL search Path:
    E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\WINXP;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext\arcade;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\pri;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64;C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Dbg\EngineExtensions;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools\;%BPADir%;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;D:\Anaconda;D:\Anaconda\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;E:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\pg95\bin;E:\Program Files\Git\cmd;E:\Program Files\nodejs\;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;E:\Utils;c:\dayforce\DayforceDEV\Utils;C:\Program Files\nodejs;c:\Program Files\WinRAR;c:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonEE9.6N\bin;C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Roaming\npm
Extension DLL chain:
    e:\utils\sosex\64\sosex.dll: image 4.6.0.0, API 1.0.0, built Mon Mar 14 10:11:26 2016
        [path: e:\utils\sosex\64\sosex.dll]
    dbghelp: image 10.0.15063.468, API 10.0.6, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\dbghelp.dll]
    ext: image 10.0.15063.468, API 1.0.0, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext\ext.dll]
    exts: image 10.0.15063.468, API 1.0.0, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\WINXP\exts.dll]
    uext: image 10.0.15063.468, API 1.0.0, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext\uext.dll]
    ntsdexts: image 10.0.15063.468, API 1.0.0, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\WINXP\ntsdexts.dll]
0:000> !lhi
0:000> .chain
Extension DLL search Path:
    E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\WINXP;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext\arcade;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\pri;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64;C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Dbg\EngineExtensions;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools\;%BPADir%;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;D:\Anaconda;D:\Anaconda\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;E:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\pg95\bin;E:\Program Files\Git\cmd;E:\Program Files\nodejs\;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;E:\Utils;c:\dayforce\DayforceDEV\Utils;C:\Program Files\nodejs;c:\Program Files\WinRAR;c:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonEE9.6N\bin;C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Roaming\npm
Extension DLL chain:
    e:\symbols\SOS_AMD64_AMD64_4.6.1590.00.dll\5787EF699e6000\SOS_AMD64_AMD64_4.6.1590.00.dll: image 4.6.1590.0, API 1.0.0, built Thu Jul 14 15:52:38 2016
        [path: e:\symbols\SOS_AMD64_AMD64_4.6.1590.00.dll\5787EF699e6000\SOS_AMD64_AMD64_4.6.1590.00.dll]
    e:\utils\sosex\64\sosex.dll: image 4.6.0.0, API 1.0.0, built Mon Mar 14 10:11:26 2016
        [path: e:\utils\sosex\64\sosex.dll]
    dbghelp: image 10.0.15063.468, API 10.0.6, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\dbghelp.dll]
    ext: image 10.0.15063.468, API 1.0.0, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext\ext.dll]
    exts: image 10.0.15063.468, API 1.0.0, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\WINXP\exts.dll]
    uext: image 10.0.15063.468, API 1.0.0, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext\uext.dll]
    ntsdexts: image 10.0.15063.468, API 1.0.0, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\WINXP\ntsdexts.dll]
```

As you can see it did not load *sos.dll*, but *e:\symbols\SOS_AMD64_AMD64_4.6.1590.00.dll\5787EF699e6000\SOS_AMD64_AMD64_4.6.1590.00.dll*, which seems to be the same thing.

Can anyone explain what is going on?

Comment: What does `lmf` say before and after `.imgscan`?

Comment: It gives a different list of modules before and after `.imgscan /l`. Before - https://pastebin.com/raw/ZitUt81q after - https://pastebin.com/raw/04XC1wgk

Comment: Before `.imgscan`, WinDbg takes the paths of the modules from the stream that contains that information. `.imgscan` then seems to replace that information. Thus, the path of `clr` is no longer available and `.loadby` does not know the path for looking for the `sos.dll`. This is similar like a dump without path information (`.dump /maR dump.dmp`)

Comment: @ThomasWeller - can you arrange your comment as the answer so I could credit you? Would be great if explained how you reached this conclusion.